# Python gui(pyautogui) function throwing a type error, what could be the issue?

Tags: python

I cloned this [repo](https://github.com/nicolomantini/LinkedIn-Easy-Apply-Bot.git) and installed everything required. The program is to apply for jobs in linkedIn. Everything works perfectly until its time to apply for the job. Then I get the error which is in pyautogui functions, which I am not allowed to change. The error is:

> File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pyautogui__init__.py", line 691, in _normalizeXYArgs
>
> return Point(int(firstArg), int(secondArg))  # firstArg and secondArg are just x and y number values
>
> TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'

You can check the code by installing pyautogui.

[Full stacktrace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aRymL.jpg)

Comment: What function from the module are you calling, and what parameters are you passing to it?

Comment: @Todd Hi there I am not a python developer but I only cloned the repo, please can you help by cloning the repo and running it. or you can install pyautogui then check init file at line 691

Comment: Please Post the complete Traceback.

Comment: If what you describe is all you did, then you should read the instructions on the repository.

Comment: @Todd everything is working properly until a certain part, the logging in, the job search work perfectly the bot stop at the job application page.

Comment: @DevanshSoni I have added the image of that at the end

Comment: @DevanshSoni it works, now I have another problem have you run the program? it get the jobs but doesn't click on Submit button. Can you fix this?

Comment: @coder254 No. I haven't run it. I just checked the code and modified it. Does it print anything when you run the Program? If yes, then post it too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `easyapplybot.py` file of the repo you cloned, in line 294, modify `avoid_lock(self)` function like this:

```
def avoid_lock(self):
        x, _ = pyautogui.position()
        pyautogui.moveTo(x+200, pyautogui.position().y, duration=1.0)
        pyautogui.moveTo(x, pyautogui.position().y, duration=0.5)
        pyautogui.keyDown('ctrl')
        pyautogui.press('esc')
        pyautogui.keyUp('ctrl')
        time.sleep(0.5)
        pyautogui.press('esc')
```

This error occurs because you can't pass `None` to `moveTo()` function of `pyautogui`. So, I've replaced `None` with `pyautogui.position().y` which the y-coordinate of position of cursor.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: it works, now I have another problem have you run the program? it get the jobs but doesn't click on Submit button. Can you fix this?

Comment: No. I haven't run it. I just checked the code and modified it. Does it print anything when you run the Program? If yes, then post it too.

Comment: it says it cannot apply for the job. It opens up to the page to submit but fails to submit. Position 1:
 Android Developer - Contract - Remote | Venturi Ltd | LinkedIn
 * has Easy Apply Button  cannot apply to this job

Comment: I'm sure there is something wrong in `try` block of `send_resume()` function (line 254), but can't solve this issue as I am not familiar with `selenium webdriver` and `BeautifulSoup`.

Comment: Thanks alot for the help